# Taking a value in a Python list, concatenating a range to it, and checking if that value is in another list

Tags: python, list, loops, range

I have 2 lists here: blk and itf

```
blk:
    ['0/3', '0/3']

itf:

    ['0/1', '0/2', '0/3', '0/4', '0/5', '0/6', '0/7', '0/8', '0/1/1', '0/1/2', '0/1/11', '0/1/12', '0/1/123', '0/1/124', '0/1/125', '0/1/126', '0/1/127', '0/1/128', '0/2/1', '0/2/2', '0/2/126', '0/2/127', '0/2/128', '0/3/127', '0/3/128', '0/4/124', '0/4/125', '0/4/126', '0/4/127', '0/4/128', '0/5/128', '0/7/128', '0/8/1', '0/1/1/1', '0/1/2/1', '0/1/2/2', '0/1/2/3', '0/1/2/4', '0/1/11/1', '0/1/11/2', '0/1/11/3', '0/1/11/4', '0/1/12/1', '0/2/1/1', '0/2/2/1', '0/2/2/32', '0/2/2/3', '0/2/2/4', '1/1', '1/2', '1/3', '1/4', '1/5', '1/6', '1/7', '1/8', '1/9', '1/10', '2/1', '2/2', '2/3', '2/4', '2/5']
```

I need to check if there exists an item in `itf` that matches whatever is in `blk` with an extra "/" and any number from 1 to 128 after it. So in this case, 0/3/127 and 0/3/128 would match and be printed to the user, ideally. The blk list could contain anywhere from 0/1 to 0/8 in it.

so far, my code looks something like this:

```
x = range(1,128)

for item in blk:
    match = item + "/" + str(x)
    if match in itf:
        print (match + "was found")
```

Right now, all it prints is a blank line. I'm not a python pro and fairly bad at understanding nested loops, so I would love to learn what mistakes im making. Thanks!

Comment: `str(x)` would be `'range(1,128)'`. you need extra for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print `match` after running your code, it's pretty quickly apparent where things are going wrong:

```
In [12]: print(match)
0/3/range(1, 128)
```

What you're actually wanting to do is loop through the elements of `range(1, 129)` (note the increment on the last term - range omits the last value given) and then append those to the string:

```
In [14]: for item in blk:
    ...:     for x in range(1, 129):
    ...:         match = item + "/" + str(x)
    ...:         if match in itf:
    ...:             print (match + " was found")
    ...:
0/3/127 was found
0/3/128 was found
0/3/127 was found
0/3/128 was found
```

You may want to consider deduplicating `blk` by casting it to a `set`:

```
In [15]: for item in set(blk):
    ...:     for x in range(1, 129):
    ...:         match = item + "/" + str(x)
    ...:         if match in itf:
    ...:             print (match + " was found")
    ...:
0/3/127 was found
0/3/128 was found
```

Comment: Oh excellent, this works perfectly. Thanks @Randy! I think the looping through the range is something I tired but improperly but this makes much more sense. Also had no idea it omitted the last value in the range - good to know!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = range(1,129)

for item in blk:
    for n in x: 
        match = item + "/" + str(n)
        if match in itf:
            print (match + "was found")
```